# advanced sorting on list

Tags: java, list, sorting

arrayForm type as below:

```
private LocalDate date;
private Integer number;
private String name;
private Object object;
```

And code like below:

```
ArrayList<ArrayForm> listArray = new ArrayList<>();
listArray.add(new ArrayForm(LocalDate.of(2018, 1, 12), 50, "First name", object));
listArray.add(new ArrayForm(LocalDate.of(2018, 1, 10), 50, "Second name", object));
listArray.add(new ArrayForm(LocalDate.of(2018, 1, 10), 50, "Third name", object));
listArray.add(new ArrayForm(LocalDate.of(2018, 1, 11), 50, "Fourth name", object));
```

what I try to do is to sort this array in few steps.

First sort by date, which I found solution like below (I'm not sure if its best solution, but it works.)

```
listArray.sort(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.getDate()));
```

And second one, if date and object are the same then merge them to one element.

Expected result:

```
2018-1-10, 100, "Second name", object
2018-1-11, 50, "Fourth name", object  
2018-1-12, 50, "First name", object
```

PS. Doesn't hardly matter if String will stay as:
"Second name", or "Third name", or will occurs by append "Second name Third name".

Any ideas how I can do it?

Comment: if you also need to merge elements, then this is not only about sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `TreeSet` or `HashSet` data structure, those by definition do not allow duplicate elements, but what you need to do then is also implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods that is override their default behaviors.

Here is a working example: https://pastebin.com/swazGxRc. It demonstrates the use of both of these data structures, but in your case because you need the elements to be sorted a `TreeSet` is preferred because it keeps the elements sorted at all times, also unlike the way I've solved this by passing a `Comparator` you could have implemented the interface `Comparable<T>` to get the same behavior which would also be the preferred option if you're going to reuse your code (i.e. sort on multiple occasions).

Comment: Good comment. Can you elaborate this more for full answer quality?

Comment: @Zabuza thanks for the tip, I added a working example.

Comment: Nice :) Can you please add the code in the answer, without a link? It's fine if you spread it over several parts and explain each part individually. It's also fine if you don't post everything and concentrate on the really relevant parts.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes `object` equality is done by `equals` method and not only by `==` same instance check.

```
Collection<ArrayForm> result = listArray.stream()
.sorted( Comparator.comparing(ArrayForm::getDate) )
.collect( Collectors.toMap( (a) -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>( a.getObject(), a.getDate() ), a -> a,
                            (a1, a2) -> { a1.setNumber( a1.getNumber() + a2.getNumber() ); return a1;} ) ).values();
```